# How to obtain/cat CPU Core Temp from ISA Adapter?

Tags: bash, debian, cpu, acpi

I'm building a script in Linux to monitor my active core temps;

Then manually enable the ACPI Fan on the event when the CORE 0 TEMP hits 40 Degrees.

I have already built the fan script that works on demand by hitting a command into the bash terminal for simplicity it is called fanon.

However I want to know how to CAT this CORE 0 temp output to a variable in a bash script called gettemp, that updates on an interval say every 2 seconds.

By using watch sensors I get the following output in the terminal.

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +45.0°C  (crit = +256.0°C)
temp2:        +36.0°C  (crit = +105.0°C)
temp3:        +32.0°C  (crit = +105.0°C)
temp4:        +24.1°C  (crit = +105.0°C)
temp5:       +100.0°C  (crit = +110.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +41.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C) <--- This is the temp I need!
Core 1:       +38.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)
```

Core 0 Temp needs to be found in a way so that I can do the following:

```
Core0Temp=$(cat /PATH/TO/ISA/TEMP/GOES/HERE)
Core1Temp=$(cat /PATH/TO/ISA/TEMP2/GOES/HERE)
```

And then from that I can do

```
if [ $Core0Temp -gt "40" ]; then
echo "Exceeding Temp Value. Enabling Fan."
/var/tempmon/fanon
elif [ $Core0Temp -lt "40" ]; then
echo "Turning Fan Off."
/var/tempmon/fanoff
fi
```

and if anyone is wondering why I need to create my own thermal mechanism, it is simply because, I am using a Compaq NX-6310 Business Laptop.

It has poor (manufacturers) ability handling of ACPI Thermal Events and its connection to the ACPI Fan, is diabolical. Many searches on Google have only showed me how to manually enable the cooling system. As shown below.

```
echo "Enabling ACPI FAN... "
echo 1 > /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device2/cur_state
echo "Fan Enabled... "
```

To disable the fan, the following is executed by sudo.

```
echo "Disabling ACPI FAN..."
echo 0 > /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device2/cur_state
echo "Fan Disabled..."
```

So I need to build this script to enable the thermal chip to report the temp, and enable the fan accordingly, like you would expect on any bog standard laptop. I just can't find where the actual core temps are located. Watch sensors can find them but I can't.

Answer (score 2):

The ACPI temperatures are under `/sys/class/thermal`, yes, but the `lm_sensors` hardware monitoring sensors are under `/sys/class/hwmon/`.

On my system, there are three sub-directories under `/sys/class/hwmon/`: there are `hwmon0`, `hwmon1` and `hwmon2`. In my case, the `coretemp` module happens to be `hwmon1`: on your system this may be different. You can identify each sub-directory simply by doing `cat /sys/class/hwmon/hwmonN/name`, where N is the number.

The `coretemp` temperature values are on my system at `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon1/temp2_input` and `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon1/temp3_input`. The numbers on those `tempN_input` filenames may also be different for you, depending on the exact CPU model. The values will be integer numbers of thousandths of degrees Celsius, i.e. 41000 will be 41.0 degrees Celsius.

Comment: I like this. very technical. a very interesting response.

Answer (score 0):

If you have sysfs mounted, which you should by default, you can find the temp readout in `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zoneX/temp`.

On my machine the following did the trick

```
$ cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp
27800
$ cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone1/temp
29800
$ sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +27.8°C  (crit = +105.0°C)
temp2:        +29.8°C  (crit = +105.0°C)
```

Comment: So would you say that temp1 is = to core 0 temp and temp2 is = to core 1 temp? 

as i am specifically after obtaining the ISA Temp Values, 
the ones reported from : coretemp-isa-0000 
and not the temps from : acpitz-virtual-0

as these appear to be different temps from different devices (for added clarity is why i ask)

Comment: as when i run the command sensors temp 1 is reporting on idle +45 whilst core 0 is reporting +37. ahhhhh 'epiphany' i think i have figured it out...! i think i may be able to pipe this through | grep and then use awk... to grab the data needed... and then just simply figure out a way to loop it on a continuous cycle to grab the same data every 2 seconds or so. and then it can run its check, on the temps of the cores, based on the integer values retrieved, and then once it hits its variable check, start and stop the ACPI fan based on that integer value recieved from the pipe - i shall try this.

Comment: But these are ACPI thermal zones, and not what lm-sensors reports in `coretemp-isa-0000`... which I think is not available in `/sys` or `/proc`.

Answer (score 0):

### 11 Hours Later.. It is alive!

--
The Birth of the ACPI Thermal CPU Superscript.

---

### i name it, tempmon!

---

i figured it all out.

- I figured out how to get that Temp Value...
- And i turned my findings into a superscript...

---

it has been an immense coding session just for this script...

hours debugging and testing, but it works like a dream...

although not quite finished, a few tweaks here and there but, 
it works, and it is continuous!

- It checks the temps,
- turns the ACPI fan on and off based on the readings of the core 0 temp,

and when it returns to low temp...

- it automatically re-runs itself, within the same process!
- with tput and setaf, $($tput $setaf $xwhite), its color coded, but you can remove those tags and keep it basic.

### It must be run as SUDO/ROOT

---

I will place the whole finished script below - As it incorporates so many commands, without the full things, it wont serve the question i posed hours ago justice, without fully, and completely answering and solving my own question without FULL CODE!

Also as this fix is actually a serious bug-fix for those within the HP Community for the Compaq NX-6310 Business Laptop! and others - perhaps, other users of this type of Laptop, may find this useful, and perhaps others with likewise ACPI Thermal Issues from the ACPI not triggering the ACPI Fan itself, in Linux Debian 9... and boom, overheating = laptop freezes.

http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/acpi-issues-overheating-badly-due-to-fan-not-coming-on-hp-nx6325.113746/

---

```
  # HP COMPAQ NX6310 - Reported Issue over@http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/acpi-issues-overheating-badly-due-to-fan-not-coming-on-hp-nx6325.113746/
  #!/bin/bash
  # TEMPMON - THE CPU/ACPI THERMAL MONITORING MECHANISM 
  #FOR THE COMPAQ NX6310 ACPI-CPU-THERMAL FAN ISSUE
  #######################
  # STACK EXCHANGE QUESTION: BY SHAUN SHORTY CASSIDY.
  # https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418919/how-to-obtain-cat-cpu-core-temp-from-isa-adapter-debian/418935#418935
  # How to obtain/cat CPU Core Temp from ISA Adapter? - Debian
  # STATUS: SOLVED BY THIS SCRIPT.
  ######################
  # Clear the Terminal
  #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  clear
  # Enter into script directory
  cd /var/tempmon/
  # Include Terminal Color Sheet.
  . ./style/colors
  ## Using Sed from:
  ## https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623835/remove-a-fixed-prefix-
  suffix-from-a-string-in-bash
  ## CREATE PREFIX AND SUFFIX FOR STRING MANIPULATION.
  tempSuffix=".0°C"
  tempPrefix="+"
  ## SET UP GUI INTERFACE
  echo "$($tput $setaf $xwhite)----------------------------------------------------"
  echo "$($tput $setaf $xcyan)       tempmon | The CPU/ACPI Thermal Monitoring Script!"
  echo "$($tput $setaf $xred)----------------------------------------------------"
  ## GET THE CORE TEMPS AT SCRIPT STARTUP.
  echo "$($tput $setaf $xwhite)Getting Core 0 temp from Sensors."
  echo "$($tput $setaf $xwhite)Getting Core 1 temp from Sensors."
  echo "$($tput $setaf $xmagenta)Getting ACPI Fan Status from Sensors."
  sleep 0.1
  #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ## READ THE SENSORS
  Core0Temp=$(sensors | grep -i "Core 0:" | awk '{print $3}')
  Core1Temp=$(sensors | grep -i "Core 1:" | awk '{print $3}')
  ## SETUP THE ACPI FAN SENSOR
  # FAN SENSOR FILE                     
  Fan0_File="/sys/class/thermal/cooling_device2/cur_state"  
  # FAN SENSOR STATUS                       
  Fan0_Status=$(cat $Fan0_File)         
  # FAN MODULE ON                           
  Fan0_On="1"                                   
  # FAN MODULE OFF                      
  Fan0_Off="0"                          
  #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  echo "$($tput $setaf $xred)----------------------------------------------------"                          
  echo "$($tput $setaf $xcyan)Configuring Core 0 temp into Readable Format."                                
  echo "$($tput $setaf $xwhite)Configuring Core 1 temp into Readable Format."                               
  ## CONFIGURE THE TEMPS FOR THE SCRIPTS USE.                   
  sleep 0.1                         
  Core0Temp1=$(echo "$Core0Temp" | sed -e "s/^$tempPrefix//" -e "s/$tempSuffix$//")             
  Core1Temp1=$(echo "$Core1Temp" | sed -e "s/^$tempPrefix//" -e "s/$tempSuffix$//")             
  echo "$($tput $setaf $xred)----------------------------------------------------"                          
  echo "$($tput $setaf $xcyan)Starting CPU Monitor: Core Temp 0: "$Core0Temp1""$tempSuffix                      
  echo "$($tput $setaf $xwhite)Starting CPU Monitor: Core Temp 1: "$Core1Temp1""$tempSuffix                     
  ## SET THE TEMP MARKER - STARTING TEMP                    
  ## SET THE TEMP START -  THRESHOLD TEMP               
  #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  tempMarker="35"
  tempIDLE=$(echo $tempMarker)                                      
  tempStart="35"
  sleep 0.1
  echo "$($tput $setaf $xred)----------------------------------------------------"                          
  echo "$($tput $setaf $xwhite)Setting Initial Temp Marker @ "$tempMarker$tempSuffix                            
  echo "$($tput $setaf $xwhite)Setting Initial Temp Threshold @ "$tempStart$tempSuffix                          
  sleep 0.1                                                 
  echo "$($tput $setaf $xred)----------------------------------------------------"                          
  ## IF CPU CORE 0 TEMP IS GREATER THAN IDLE TEMP OF 35;THEN RUN LOOP..                         
  ## (HAS TO BE LOW TO TRIGGER THE LOOP)        
  #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                #
  while true; do
  if [ $Core0Temp1 -gt $tempMarker ]; then                                  
      ## THEN NOTIFY TERMINAL THAT TEMP HAS EXCEEDED THRESHOLD TEMP                         
      echo "$($tput $setaf $xyellow)###################################################"    
      echo "$($tput $setaf $xwhite)        Exceeding Temp of: $($tput $setaf $xcyan)"$tempStart$tempSuffix                                  
      echo "$($tput $setaf $xyellow)###################################################"
      ## NOTIFY USER THAT MACHINE IS ENABLING THE ACPI FAN... (REQUIRES SUDO TO DO)                 
      echo "$($tput $setaf $xred)======================================================="   
      echo "$($tput $setaf $xcyan)--------------            Checking the ACPI Fan."                                         
      echo "$($tput $setaf $xwhite)====================================================="   
      ## THEN ENABLE THE FAN UNTIL;                                         
      ## but before enabling the fan... we must check to see if it is already active... 
      ## no point turning on a lightbulb when its already on...
      if [ $Fan0_Status -eq $Fan0_On  ]; then
        echo "$($tput $setaf $xyellow)/////////////////////////////////////////////"        
        echo "$($tput $setaf $xwhite)              ERROR! --- ACPI Fan 0: Already Enabled!"
        echo "$($tput $setaf $xyellow)/////////////////////////////////////////////"            
            elif [ $Fan0_Status -eq $Fan0_Off ]; then
                echo $Fan0_On > $Fan0_File      
                echo "$($tput $setaf $xyellow)/////////////////////////////////////////////"                                    
                echo "$($tput $setaf $xwhite)             ACPI Fan 0: Enabling..."                                          
                echo "$($tput $setaf $xyellow)/////////////////////////////////////////////"
    fi
echo "----------------------------------------------------"                         
      ## Until Loop: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29692893/read-variable-until-output-is-greater-than-a-certain-value-in-bash
  #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  until [ ${Core0Temp1} -lt $tempStart ]; do                                    
      sleep 1                                                       
      ## CORE 0 TEMP RETURNS TO LESS THAN THE THRESHOLD TEMP;                               
      ## RUN EVERY SECOND                                               
      ## ON EVERY SECOND GET UPDATED TEMP VALUES                                    
      ## AND ON EVERY SECOND GET THE ACPI FAN CURRENT STATUS (SUDO NEEDED!)                     
Fan0_Status=$(cat $Fan0_File) 
    if [ $Fan0_Status -eq $Fan0_On ]; then                                      
        sleep 1
        echo "$($tput $setaf $xyellow)/////////////////////////////////////////////"
        echo "$($tput $setaf $xwhite)                               ACPI_FAN0 IS ENABLED"                                       
        echo "$($tput $setaf $xyellow)/////////////////////////////////////////////"
    elif [ $Fan0_Status -eq $Fan0_Off ]; then
        sleep 1
        echo "$($tput $setaf $xyellow)/////////////////////////////////////////////"
        echo "$($tput $setaf $xwhite)                               ACPI_FAN0 IS DISABLED"
        echo "$($tput $setaf $xyellow)/////////////////////////////////////////////"
    fi
Core0Temp=$(sensors | grep -i "Core 0:" | awk '{print $3}')                         
Core0Temp1=$(echo "$Core0Temp" | sed -e "s/^$tempPrefix//" -e "s/$tempSuffix$//")               
## DISPLAY THE UPDATED TEMP VALUES TO THE TERMINAL                              
echo "Core 0 Temp IS: "$Core0Temp1""$tempSuffix                                 
## THEN ALSO EVERY SECOND, RUN A CHECK TO SEE IF THE TEMP                           
## HAS RETURNED TO LESS THAN THE THRESHOLD TEMP                                 
    if [ $Core0Temp1 -lt $tempStart ]; then                                     
        ## IF THE TEMP HAS RETURNED TO LESS THAN THE THRESHOLD TEMP                         
        ## THEN DISABLE THE FAN AND NOTIFY TERMINAL                                 
        ## but again, run a check to first see if it is active.
        ## you cant turn of a light thats already off right? ;)
        ## if active then disable. if not, then dont. cause its off.
        if [ $Fan0_Status -eq $Fan0_Off  ]; then
            echo "$($tput $setaf $xyellow)/////////////////////////////////////////////"                
            echo "$($tput $setaf $xwhite)/                   ERROR!                   /"
            echo "$($tput $setaf $xyellow)/////////////////////////////////////////////"
            echo "$($tput $setaf $xwhite)/        ACPI Fan 0: Already Disabled!       /"
            echo "$($tput $setaf $xyellow)/////////////////////////////////////////////"
        elif [ $Fan0_Status -eq $Fan0_On ]; then
            echo $Fan0_Off > $Fan0_File
            echo "$($tput $setaf $xcyan)###################################################"                                                                                     #
            echo "$($tput $setaf $xyellow)------------ACPI Fan 0: Disabled ./"
            echo "$($tput $setaf $xcyan)###################################################"                                                                                    #
        fi
        echo "$($tput $setaf $xwhite)###################################################"
        echo "$($tput $setaf $xcyan)--------- Core Temp Returned to: @"$tempStart""$tempSuffix
        echo "$($tput $setaf $xwhite)###################################################"
    fi
  done
  #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  #fi   # this fi gets moved down under the return block.
  #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ## So what do we do if the temp is less than the predefined temp?
  ## We repeat the until function but, in a reverse order.
  ## this is so that the script runs in a kind of (>---<>---<) see saw effect...
  ## back and fourth, to and fro right.
  until [ ${Core0Temp1} -gt $tempStart ]; do                                    
   sleep 1                                                      
## CORE 0 TEMP RETURNS TO LESS THAN THE THRESHOLD TEMP;                             
## RUN EVERY SECOND                                             
## ON EVERY SECOND GET UPDATED TEMP VALUES                                  
## AND ON EVERY SECOND GET THE ACPI FAN CURRENT STATUS (SUDO NEEDED!)                       
Fan0_Status=$(cat $Fan0_File) 
    if [ $Fan0_Status -eq $Fan0_Off ]; then                                     
        sleep 1
        echo "$($tput $setaf $xwhite)/////////////////////////////////////////////"             
        echo "$($tput $setaf $xwhite)--------------------ACPI_FAN0 IS DISABLED./"
        echo "$($tput $setaf $xwhite)/////////////////////////////////////////////"             
    elif [ $Fan0_Status -eq $Fan0_On ]; then
        sleep 1
        echo "$($tput $setaf $xwhite)/////////////////////////////////////////////"             
        echo "$($tput $setaf $xwhite)--------------------ACPI_FAN0 IS ENABLED/./"
        echo "$($tput $setaf $xwhite)/////////////////////////////////////////////"             
    fi
      Core0Temp=$(sensors | grep -i "Core 0:" | awk '{print $3}')                           
      Core0Temp1=$(echo "$Core0Temp" | sed -e "s/^$tempPrefix//" -e "s/$tempSuffix$//")             
## DISPLAY THE UPDATED TEMP VALUES TO THE TERMINAL
echo "$($tput $setaf $xwhite)==============================================="                               
echo "$($tput $setaf $xwhite)           Core 0 Temp IS: "$Core0Temp1""$tempSuffix           
echo "$($tput $setaf $xwhite)==============================================="                       
## THEN ALSO EVERY SECOND, RUN A CHECK TO SEE IF THE TEMP                           
## HAS RETURNED TO LESS THAN THE THRESHOLD TEMP                                 
    if [ $Core0Temp1 -gt $tempStart ]; then                                     
        ## IF THE TEMP HAS RETURNED TO greater THAN THE THRESHOLD TEMP                          
        ## THEN ENABLE THE FAN AND NOTIFY TERMINAL                                  
        ## but again, run a check to first see if it is active.
        ## you cant turn ON a light thats already ON right? ;)
        ## if active then disable. if not, then dont. cause its off.
        if [ $Fan0_Status -eq $Fan0_On  ]; then
            echo "$($tput $setaf $xyellow)/////////////////////////////////////////////"                
            echo "$($tput $setaf $xwhite)                  ERROR!                   /"
            echo "$($tput $setaf $xyellow)/////////////////////////////////////////////"
            echo "$($tput $setaf $xwhite)        ACPI Fan 0: Already Enabled!       /"
            echo "$($tput $setaf $xyellow)/////////////////////////////////////////////"
        elif [ $Fan0_Status -eq $Fan0_Off ]; then
            echo $Fan0_On > $Fan0_File
            echo "$($tput $setaf $xred)-------------------------------------------"                                                                                      #
            echo "$($tput $setaf $xwhite)................ACPI Fan 0: Enabled.."
            echo "$($tput $setaf $xred)-------------------------------------------"                                                                                     #
        fi
        echo "$($tput $setaf $xred)###################################################"
        echo "$($tput $setaf $xwhite)............Core Temp dropping below: @"$tempStart""$tempSuffix
        echo "$($tput $setaf $xred)###################################################"
        echo "$($tput $reset)"
    fi
  done
  #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  fi
done
#END OF SUPERSCRIPT.
```

Comment: You might find `fancontrol` useful — install it, then run `sudo pwmconfig`.